# I cannot access an object property

Tags: java, rdf, jena, object-properties

I'm using Java and Jena API.
I have a ***class Marriage*** which have 3 Object Properties called "**hasHusband**", "**Haswife**" and "**dateOfMarriage**". The first two are associated with a ***class Person*** which has the datatypeproperties like **hasFirstName**, **hasLastName**, **dateOfBirth**....

I'd like to access the objects properties "Haswife" and "hasHusband" and then the wife's first name and the husband's first name.

**Here is how that is represented in my rdf file:**

(...)

```
  <j.0:FAMmariage rdf:about=http://www.fam.com/FAM#BrunoCatherine> 

  <j.0:FAMaDateMariage>25/07/2011</j.0:FAMaDateMariage>

   <j.0:FAMhasWife>
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.fam.com/FAM#Catherine20/03/1982">
       <j.0:FAMDateOfBirth>20/03/1980</j.0:FAMDateOfBirth>
       <j.0:FAMHasName>Gomez</j.0:FAMHasName>
       <j.0:FAMHasFirstName>Catherine</j.0:FAMHasFirstName>
    </rdf:Description>
  </j.0:FAMHasWife>

   <j.0:FAMHusband>
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.fam.com/FAM# Bruno15/06/1980 ">
       <j.0:FAMaDateOfBirth>15/06/1980 </j.0:FAMDateOfBirth>
       <j.0:FAMHasName>Jeandet </j.0:FAMHasName>
       <j.0:FAMHasFirstName>Bruno</j.0:FAMHasFirstName>
     </rdf:Description>
   </j.0:FAMHusband>

 </j.0:FAMmariage>
(...)
```

**I tried like this but it still does not works:**

```
StmtIterator iter = onto.model.listStatements();  
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();  
        Resource  subject = stmt.getSubject();     
        Property  predicate = stmt.getPredicate();   
        RDFNode   object = stmt.getObject();
        if (predicate.equals(onto.hasWife))
        {       
           System.out.print(" " + object.toString() + " ");
        }
  }
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Thanks

**EDITED**

More useful details:

(...)

```
person = model.createClass(uriBase+"person");
person.addSubClass(man);
person.addSubClass(woman);
marriage = model.createClass(uriBase+"marriage");
```

(...)

```
hasHusband = model.createObjectProperty(uriBase+"hasHusband");
hasHusband.setDomain(marriage);
hasHusband.setRange(man);

hasWife = model.createObjectProperty(uriBase+"hasWife");
hasWife.setDomain(marriage);
hasWife.setRange(woman);

hasFirstName = model.createDatatypeProperty(uriBase+"hasFirstName"); 
hasFirstName.setDomain(person);
hasFirstName.setRange(XSD.xstring);
```

(...)

Comment: how have you defined onto.hasWife ?

Comment: This RDF/XML code is hurting my eyes! Moreover, there is a syntax error on the first line, quotes missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does that work ?

```
ont.hasWife=model.createProperty("your namespace URI here","FAMhasWife");

StmtIterator iter = onto.model.listStatements(null,onto.hasWife,(RDFNode)null);  
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();  

           System.out.print(stmt.getObject().toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

With the information you provide it's impossible to know what's the problem exactly. It is possible that you made a mistake in one of your URIs, either in your data or in your programme. Your question is inconcistent wrt naming terms.

May I suggest a few things? First, use the datatypes `xsd:date` or even `xsd:dateTime` for dates of marriage and dates of birth. Use the YYYY-MM-DD pattern for naming entities as this sorts them chronologically if sorted lexicographically. Use consistent naming convention, e.g., `hasWife` and `hasHusband` instead of `hasWife` and `husband`. "Marriage" has two "r" in English. Use a meaningful prefix when presenting your data to people. Better, use a human friendly syntax such as Turtle.

```
fam:BrunoCatherine  a  fam:Marriage;
    fam:dateOfMarriage  "2011-07-25"^^xsd:date;
    fam:hasWife  fam:Catherine1982-03-20;
    fam:hasHusband  fam:Bruno1980-06-15 .
fam:Catherine1982-03-20  fam:dateOfBirth  "1982-03-20"^^xsd:date;
    fam:hasLastName  "Gomez";
    fam:hasFirstName  "Catherine" .
fam:Bruno1980-06-15  fam:dateOfBirth  "1980-06-15"^^xsd:date;
    fam:hasLastName  "Jeandet";
    fam:hasFirstName  "Bruno" .
```

Doesn't it look nicer?